# I cannot get this very very simple jQuery to run

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to hide

```
<div id="correctinterface">

Correct!

</div>
```

I want to hide the above

but

```
$("#correctinterface").hide();
```

does not do the job

```
$("#correctinterface").css("display", "none");
```

does not do the job either

I did it on jfiddle and Google Chrome version 36

thanks a lot

Comment: Where is the CSS3? Can you show your fiddle?

Comment: are you doing this inside $(document).ready(function(){//enter code here}); ?

Comment: mostly you have `display: block !important;` somewhere in your CSS files. Or not firing this JS in the right time. Can you show the jsfiddle you have?

Comment: have you included jQuery? is browser console showing some error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
$(function () {
    $("#correctinterface").hide();
});
```

If it works then your problem is that you need to wrap your jQuery code in [$(document).ready()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) which fires once the document is loaded.

Here is a quick [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ramynasr/vPF6t/) for it.

Comment: I said try that, didn't i?

Comment: Ramy, excellent job.  This solved the issue.  Care to tell me a bit about why it did not work?

Comment: I added why to the answer and a link about document `ready()` to read about it. You might need to refresh the page.

Comment: This works because `$("#correctinterface").hide();` is executed after the document is ready, i.e all the elements has been rendered, so now id *correctinterface* can be found on document because the div has been rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HE7Gz/) showing .hide() in action.

```
$("#correctinterface").click(function(){
   $("#correctinterface").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Ramy's answer, the jQuery function...

```
$(function () {
    // Your code here
    $("#correctinterface").hide();
});
```

... ensures that any code inside of it is run after the page has loaded, including the div you want it to find with the id `#correctinterface`. Otherwise it won't find it because it doesn't exist and hence won't hide it.